# Magento 2 : How To Create UNIQUE KEY Field in Custom Tabel

Tags: magento2, sql, table

I want to create custom filed say `myname` with constraints UNIQUE KEY in custom extension table.

In Magento1 we can define like this :

```
UNIQUE KEY `myname` (`myname`)
```

How can I do this in Magento2?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use Index Type as

**Old Way: Using setup script**

`\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE`

To add unique key use code,

```
->addIndex(
    $installer->getIdxName(
        'YOUR_TABLE_NAME',
        ['YOUR_UNIQUE_FIELD_NAME'],
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
    ),
    ['YOUR_UNIQUE_FIELD_NAME'],
    ['type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE]
)
```

You can add multiple column combination as `UNIQUE` with,

```
->addIndex(
    $installer->getIdxName(
        'catalog_product_entity_datetime',
        ['entity_id', 'attribute_id', 'store_id'],
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
    ),
    ['entity_id', 'attribute_id', 'store_id'],
    ['type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE]
)
```

Refer `vendor\magento\module-catalog\Setup\InstallSchema.php`

**New Way:Using DB Schema**

MyCompany/MyModule/etc/db_schema.xml :

```
<constraint xsi:type="unique" referenceId="DIRECTORY_COUNTRY_FORMAT_COUNTRY_ID_TYPE">
    <column name="country_id"/>
    <column name="type"/>
</constraint>
```

**Full Snap code:**  https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Directory/etc/db_schema.xml

Comment: let me try this.

Comment: Please add magento version to your sollution. Then we know it's still usefull in the future. Magento 2.3 uses declarative-schema for example. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 2.3, We can create unique key using declarative schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="student" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Student Table">
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="student_id" padding="6" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Student Id"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="roll_number" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Roll Number"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="student_name" nullable="true" comment="Student Name"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="student_id"/>
        </constraint>
        <constraint xsi:type="unique" referenceId="STUDENT_ROLL_NUMBER">
            <column name="roll_number"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

for more details refer https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html